# How can I put the outcome of a for loop in each column of a matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a code below:

```
a=zeros(5,1);
f=zeros(5,5);
for i=1:5
a(i,1)=5;
 f(:,i)=a;
end
```

I want the result of each loop to be each columns of matrix f. I mean f=[a(1) a(2) a(3) a(4) a(5)] in which a(i) has come from each loop in for loop. but the outcome is:

```
 5     5     5     5     5
 0     5     5     5     5
 0     0     5     5     5
 0     0     0     5     5
 0     0     0     0     5
```

I'm new to matlab. It is appreciated if you tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I've read it several times and I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Could you show us what your desired outcome is?

Comment: for example for i=1, I have a new 'a' which is a(i=1)=[5;0;0;0;0]. also for i=2, I have a(i=2)=[0;5;0;0;0] and so on.  I want matrix 'f' to be made of these outcomes as its columns. like this: f=[5 0 0 0 0; 0 5 0 0 0; 0 0 5 0 0; 0 0 0 5 0; 0 0 0 0 5]. I know i can make a diagonal matrix but i need to use this form.

Comment: even if you still need a loop, you can drop the use of `a`. `for k=1:5 ; a(k,k)=5; end`. Otherwise what you did wrong is you forgot to reset `a` at each iteration, so `a` is not _new_ as you think, it remembers every assignment you did at previous iterations.

Comment: yes, you're right. I renewed 'a' in each iteration and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Do like this**

```
a=zeros(5,1);
f=zeros(5,5);
a(:,1)=5;
f(1,:)=transpose(a);
```

Comment: You sure? I think he's trying to change the f matrix.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I did not read the question properly :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that in line 4 you have a(:,1)=5. Since it is on a loop the value of a continues to expand so that you first have a(1)=5, a(2)= 5 5, a(3)= 5 5 5, etc. What you want to do is specify what specific value of a you want in your matrix f. You can do this by:

a=zeros(5,1);

f=zeros(5);

for i=1:5

a(i,1)=5;

f(i,i)=a(i,1);
end

disp(f)